# Edit List Forms in SharePoint Desinger to show attach file in list form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I'm trying to edit my new form and edit form in a customer sp list in SP Designer, so users can upload files directly while completing the form, rather than remembering to scroll up to the ribbon and attach it there.

I found this blog post that provides info to do it in spd 2007, but the functionality is not the same, and I'm having issues.
http://dishasharepointworld.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-customize-edit-forms-in_22.html#comment-form

I also found this:  http://sharepoint.indigoreality.com/2012/06/18/sharepoint-2010-adding-an-attachments-field-to-a-list-item-form/
But some steps are missing.

Anyone out there that can help, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Within SPD, I did the following.  First, I didn't edit the existing new item file.  I created a new one.  Then I did advance edit.  Deleted the text from a field that I didn't need in the new item form.  Replaced the verbiage with Attach File.  Then, where the field was, I deleted the checkbox in my case and drag and dropped an .net file upload control.  Works like a charm.